# Primitivity of CRC polynomials

Tags: crc

I found the following in the web about the performance of CRCs:

> Primitive polynomial. This has optimal length for HD=3, and good HD=2
>   performance above that length.

I don't get it. Optimal length for HD=3 is understandable; but what does good HD=2 performance mean? AFAIK all CRCs have infinite data length at HD=2.

So what does "good HD=2 performance above that length" for primitive polynomials mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Author said: "Generally the primitive polynomials tend to have pretty good (i.e., low) weights at HD=2 compared to many other polynomials. It has been a while since I looked, but I think in all cases right above the HD=2 break point the lowest weight polynomial was always primitive."

For some algorithm implementation low weight may provide faster computation.

Comment: For others reading this, low weights means the number of (non-zero) coefficients in a polynomial. There's no natural tendency for primitive polynomials to have low weights, they have to be "searched" for. Typically, there's no difference in computation speed for lower weights, since software typically uses tables, and hardware uses a Galois shift register where the XOR's are done in parallel. Lower weight does reduce the number of XOR gates in hardware. In the case of software using carryless multiply, such as X86 pclmulqdq, the multiply time is fixed and not dependent on number of 1 bits.

Comment: Regarding calculation I think you are right. Nobody uses bit-wise algorithms in reality. Regarding low weights of primitive polynomials it was a bit different what the Author said. I am using the phrasing of the Author now.

Answer (score 1):

> ... has optimal length for HD=3, and good HD=2 performance above that length.

The statement is poorly worded. I find it at the bottom of this web page under "Notation:"

https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc

In this and other articles I find, the abbreviation "HD" represents the minimum Hamming Distance for a CRC: for HD=k+1, then the CRC can detect any pattern of k bit errors in a message up to some length (as shown in the tables). As you stated, "all CRCs have infinite data length at HD=2".

The usage of the phrase "good HD=2 performance above that length" is confusing. The web site above links to the web site below which includes the statement "HD=2 lengths are always infinite, and so are always left out of this list."

https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/notes.html

---

[Wiki hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance#Error_detection_and_error_correction) explains the relationship between bit error detection and Hamming distance: "a code C is said to be k error detecting if, and only if, the minimum Hamming distance between any two of its codewords is at least k+1" 
As you stated, "all CRCs have infinite data length at HD=2", meaning all CRCs can detect any single bit error regardless of message length.

As for "optimal length for HD=3", which means being able to detect a 2 bit error, consider a [linear feedback shift register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register) based on the CRC polynomial, initialized with any non-zero value, if you cycle the register enough times, it will end up back with that initial value. For a n bit CRC based on a n+1 bit primitive polynomial, the register will cycle through all 2^n - 1 non-zero values before repeating. The maximum length of the message (which is the length of data plus the length of CRC) where no failure to detect a 2 bit error can occur is 2^n - 1. For a message of length 2^n or greater, then for any "i", if bit[0+i] and bit[(2^n)-1+i] are in error, the primitive CRC will fail to detect the 2 bit error. If the CRC polynomial is not primitive, the the maximum length for failproof 2 error bit detection will be decreased, and not "optimal".

For a linear feedback shift register based on any CRC polynomial, initialized to any non-zero value, no matter how many times it it cycled, it will never include a value of zero. This is one way to explain why "all CRCs have infinite data length at HD=2" (are able to detect single bit errors).

Comment: After reading your post it strikes me that my problem arises due to bad wording. There obviously are two meanings for the term "Hamming Distance / HD". The first is the "lowest weight of any undetectable error" (aka. "minimum HD"). And the second is "number of positions at which data are different". I guess the mentioned source uses both meanings synonymous. Assuming the second meaning, the citation make sense.

Comment: Alas my assumption is wrong. 
See this table: https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/crc6.html
The {data sizes} start with HD=3 (read "minimum HD").  HD=2 is not listed there since the data size is infinite. The primitive (*p) polynomials are optimal at HD=3 (as cited). Still I do not understand the "good HD=2 performance above that length" from the notes page.

Comment: Why do you think Koopman's pages at http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/notes.html are outdated? And where did you find a newer page?

Comment: @Silicomancer - I updated my answer. The term "Hamming distance" means the number of differing bits between two messages (codewords), so that a Hamming distance of 2 could mean a 2 bit error versus a valid message. However in the articles I've found, the abbreviation "HD" stands for minimal Hamming distance for an error detection (or correction) code, such as CRC. If HD=k+1, then a CRC can detect up to k bit errors in a message up to some length as indicated by the tables. As you stated, "all CRCs have infinite data length at HD=2".

Comment: @Silicomancer - note it's the same author that wrote "good HD=2 performance", and "HD=2 lengths are always infinite". I would suggest the first phrase be reworded.